# Reference for Zariski Main Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-space

Let $\pi: X \to B$ be an elliptic surface with a section $\sigma$.
Assume that $\pi, X, B$ are all smooth and that $X,B$ are projective.

Let $\mathcal M(r,d)_{X/B}$ be the relative moduli space of stable vector bundles of rank r on fibers with degree d.

I have seen a few times using ZMT (Zariski main theorem) used the following way:

> Claim: Assume there is an injective map $\phi:X \to \mathcal M(r,d)_{X/B}$.
> Then by ZMT, $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

I am looking for references for the above usage of ZMT. I looked into [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00PI) and [here](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/ZMTfull.pdf) but could not a version or a ZMT corollary suitable for the claim.

Thank you for any hint or reference.

Comment: Does Corollary 3.9 in your second reference not suffice?

Comment: I checked this corollary but couldn't derive properness assumption from injectivity assumption and couldn't see why the map would be birational.